# Stopping Heap Growth Related to a Core Data Managed Object

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, instruments

I'm noticing some heap growth when I run instruments.  There are no leaks but there is some memory that is not clearing that looks to be caused by my use of core data.

[image: instruments screenshot]

From the stack trace it seems the growth happens when I save the managed object.

**This is how I'm creating the managed object:**

```
ScramblerGame *game = (ScramblerGame *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ScramblerGame" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
game.time = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.time];
game.score = 0; //etc...
```

ScramblerGame is a managed object subclass created right from the data model with no modifications.

**This is how I'm accessing and updating the managed object:**

```
self.game.score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.game.score intValue] + score];
```

`self.game` is a weak reference in another class to the managed object.

**This is the method called at the end of a game that saves or deletes the data.**  It is also the last of my methods called in the stack trace of the referenced image, which is leading to the heap growth.

```
-(void)saveAndHandleGameData:(BOOL)stillPlaying{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:nil];

//save the data to disk
self.game.inProgress = [NSNumber numberWithBool:stillPlaying];
SCAppDelegate *appDelegate = ((SCAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]);
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

if([self.game.score intValue] == 0)
    [context deleteObject:self.game];
[context save:nil];
self.game = nil;

}
```

So am I doing anything wrong with core data that is causing this?  Any advice on how to stop the heap growth?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks OK. The minimal increase in memory can be regarded as normal and should be expected.